# Unable to open symlinks on FTP connection with Eclipse RSE. Getting 550 I can only retrieve regular files

Tags: eclipse, ftp, symlink, eclipse-rse

I want to connect to my FTP account using Eclipse RSE. I created a new connection. Everything fine. But in my FTP Folder there are symlinks pointing to different folders on the servers. When i try to open the symlinks RSE tells me

**550 I can only retrieve regular files**

With a normal FTP Browser like FileZilla i can open an browse those symlinks! Are symlinks not supported by RSE?

I use
 
**Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911**

Any Ideas?